# the property timestamp on posgress

Tags: postgresql, post

I have two data base in two differents machines with the same schemas, tables and data. I launch this query:

```
select mydate from mytable where date = '2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamp::date
```

the first machine return the correct rows and the second one doesn´t, both machines has the same prostgres version (9.2)

the only different between the machines is that first one works on windows and the second one on Linux (Centos)

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is data type of column mydate and date in table mytable?

Comment: is timestamp with time zone in both tables the type of column is the same

Comment: I am sure that problem is in default time zone. Try to set time zone before execute this query `SET TIME ZONE '-07';` on the machine where you receive incorrect result. ('-07' - is an example, you must put there the default time zone from first machine)

Comment: Also check timestamp format on doth machines - by default postgres picks the timestamp format of host OS.

Comment: @Nicolai It is better to set default timezone for database before it was restored from dump. Othervise postgres can interpret timestamps inside dump with wrong timezone.

Comment: Thanks all, at the end I resolved it with:                       select mydate from mytable where date::timestamp::date = '2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamp::date

Answer (score 1):

`'2013-10-03'` can be interpreted as *Oct, 3rd* or *March, 10th*, depending on your [`datestyle`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting. [@Chris has more on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20137707/939860)

In addition to that, your query is **generally incorrect**. This expression is misleading:

```
'2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamp
```

`timestamp` in Postgres defaults to `timestamp without time zone`, which doesn't recognize time zone offsets. Therefore, the time zone offset `-07` is **discarded**.

Use instead:

```
'2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamptz
```

#### Match the **point in time**:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mydate = '2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamptz
```

Does *not depend* on your local time zone setting, since the data type of the column is `timestamp with time zone` as you clarified in a later comment.

#### Match the **day**:

```
...
WHERE mydate::date = '2013-10-03 14:25:00-07'::timestamptz::date
```

*Depends* on your local time zone setting, which defines lower and upper borders of the "day".

Detailed explanation in this related answer:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution would be to, at the beginning of the session, just issue the following command:

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, YMD";
```

This will ensure properly handling the timestamp according to your input format.